# Create Kubernetes storage Google Compute Engine

Tags: kubernetes, google-compute-engine

I have two Ubuntu machines, kmaster and knode (VM Instances) with Kubernetes installed (self install).

How can I create volume in yaml file to directory on `kmaster` on Google computer engine?
I want to data remain after pods kill (persistant volume).

Comment: How did you install Kubernetes?

Comment: It's just  2 vm's that I install kubernetes by myself (that's because I need vms with vmx support)

Comment: Yes but how did you install it.

Comment: Using  this  one https://medium.com/edureka/install-kubernetes-on-ubuntu-5cd1f770c9e4 D:

Comment: If you did everything from scratch, you will have to configure a compatible kubernetes storage provider that is able to attach Google persistent disks to your nodes that can be used as persistent volumes. See more here https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/storage-classes/